# Insert jpg image to pdf page included by pdfpages

Tags: pdfpages, jpeg

For a university project, I have to attach a form, which is provided by the university, to my project right after the abstract, and fill in the details using latex. I managed to do this using `\includepdf` as the following code shows.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Abstract}

This is the text of the abstract

\includepdf[pages={1}, pagecommand={},
 picturecommand*={%
  \put(340,648){My Name}%
  \put(206,585){My Surname}%
  \put(270,558){The University name}%
  \put(182,531){The name of the course}%
  \put(80,101){The date}%
}]{theformname.pdf}
\end{document}
```

However, I also need a copy of my signature on this page. So I scanned my signature and saved it as a jpg image. Is there a way to include it in this page and place it in its correct position, similar to what I did for my name, surname, etc.? Many thanks

Comment: Something like `\put(..,..){\includegraphics{signature}}` should work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add images like you added the text:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Abstract}

This is the text of the abstract

\includepdf[pages={1}, pagecommand={},
 picturecommand*={%
  \put(340,648){My Name}%
  \put(206,585){My Surname}%
  \put(270,558){The University name}%
  \put(182,531){The name of the course}%
  \put(80,101){The date}%
  \put(200,400){\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
}]{example-image-a4}
\end{document}
```

[image]